# how to make variables preserved after endlocal command

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

Thanks Nate. It works.
But now i need output variable for this script to use later.
There are 2 outputs i need. First is count variable as integer output, second is string variable which is equal to last string character in "word".
So, i need this 2 variable as you see in last row of finished script before "press any key to continue...".
1 last integer variable and 1 last string variable.

I need these 2 variables for later scripting in this script.
How i can have it?
Here is a script which works from yesterday.

```
@ECHO OFF
:input
set /p word=input your word:
if not defined word goto input
(ECHO %word%)> tempfile.txt
FOR %%x IN (tempfile.txt) DO ( SET /A lenght=%%~zx - 2 )

del tempfile.txt
echo %word% got %lenght% characters
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%m in (1,1,!lenght!) do (
  set /a count=%%m
  set /a index=%%m-1
  call echo !count! %%word:~!index!,1%%
) 

(call echo %%word:~!index!,1%%)>tf.txt


for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (tf.txt) do (
set line=%%a
set char=!line:~0,1!

)

pause

echo %count% %char%

endlocal

pause
```

Comment: is it good now for others to understand?

Comment: the forum soft did obstuct me formatting your question better. please do it yourself.

Comment: look on this finished code. works when endlocal is at the end. i got 2 variables( one last integer and one last string ). but not working if i put endlocal after create tf.txt. can you make work on this way if endlocal is in next line after creation of tf.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this technic to tear down the wall of `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` / `endlocal`:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "word=abcdefghij"
set /a lenght=10

for /l %%m in (1,1,%lenght%) do (
    set /a $count=%%m
    set /a index=%%m-1
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    call echo !$count! %%word:~!index!,1%%
    call set "$laststring=%%word:~!index!,1%%"
    for /f %%i in ('set $') do (if "!"=="" endlocal)& set "%%i"
)
echo( 
echo !$count! !$laststring!
echo %$count% %$laststring%
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13772031/2098699))

Comment: I only can say, that you make it again. do you sleep on book instead of pillow? you are genious. please if you can send me via mail brief explanation of every piece of your code i will be very greatfull to you. mail is zeusaluminium@gmail.com .

Comment: i mean thoroughly and slow explanation. i was thinking that "brief"=slow and thoroughly, so type in google and find out that i use this word for wrong purpose:). learn every day:)

Comment: `delayed expansion` doesn't mean "slow", it means "later" :)

Comment: if i enebledelayedexpansion does this mean that all variables with !(exclamation mark) will developed at the same time in eni position in that block of enabledelayedexpansion??

Comment: delayed expansion means, the parser doesn't interpret `!variable!`s.

Example:

`@echo off                          `
`setlocal                           `
`set "uglyvar=^^&!&dir"             `
`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    `
`echo !uglyvar!                     `
`pause                              `
`echo %uglyvar%                     `
`                                   `

Comment: who is parser in your code?

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/2098699), how does the parser work.

Comment: thanks, i need at least two days to put these things in my head. so on tuesday i will be back on this article if will have something to ask. you helped me a lot with your time and examples;)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways documented [here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php#FunctionTutorial.ReturningLocalVariables) that show how to do this, however `endlocal & set global=local` is my favourite.

Judging by what I think you want...

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%m in (1,1,!lenght!) do (
    set /a count=%%m
    set /a index=%%m-1
    call echo !count! %%word:~!index!,1%%
    set laststring=%word:~!index!,1%
) 
(
    endlocal
    set count=%count%
    set laststring=%laststring%
)
```

Comment: Ah, but `endlocak&set global=%local%` is more likely to produce the desired results... :)

Comment: can somebody finish this script on way i asked, cause i dont know?

Comment: @Zvonimir What variables do you want to keep, and what variables do you want to save them as?

Comment: i want to keep last counter number and last string character

Comment: @Zvonimir I can't make out what you mean by that. Do you want `%count%` and `%index%`, or do you want something completely different. Edited the question to reflect what I mean.

Comment: i want %count% and some %laststring% witch not defined

Comment: @Zvonimir What do you want `%laststring%` to contain?

Comment: i want to contain last character from echo in this script

Comment: this will be the index position character, but character as string

Comment: @Zvonimir So should `%laststring%` have the value of `%%word:~!index!,1%%`, or `%index%`?

Comment: it must be value of %%word:~!index!,1%%

Comment: for example if word was "qwertz" it must be "z"

Comment: i must use this "z" and %count% in later calculation, so i need to have them as 2 variables, "z" is string variable; %count% is integer variable

Comment: @Zvonimir Edited it. Does it look right?

Comment: i tried to echo these 2 variables, but doesnt work. i make: echo %count %laststring% but no good echoing?!?

Comment: echo %count% %laststring% echoing "laststring"?!?

Comment: @Zvonimir What about now?

Comment: doesnt work, echoing only "laststring"

Comment: In case of `delayedexpansion` this will never work so. You need an other technique to break through the wall!

Comment: like ever in batch, a for loop will help.

Comment: please construct this work if you know how. you helped me with "call" 2 days ago.

Comment: go shopping now, later back :-)

Comment: Read here [SO:Make an environment variable survive ENDLOCAL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3262287/463115) for different solutions

Comment: thanks for link but too complicated on this way for me. i dont have enough knowledge to understand all of that. just trying to understand how can i have variable stay after this situation.

Comment: so i put that last character in txt.file with (call echo %%word:~!index!,1%%)>tf.txt  last character is now only character in tf.txt is it way to load this character in batch file after endlocal, as string variable???

Comment: There are many situations where this method will fail. See answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3262287/1012053 for more reliable methods.